# GAE Python Unittest Runner

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, python-unittest

I have a Python API running on Google's Cloud Endpoints framework.

I'm trying to implement a runner for my unittests, using the dev_appserver.

I've copied and adapted what Google is offering about this, just edited a bit to make it run the devappserver all-in-one.

This is what I've done so far:

```
import argparse
import os
import sys
import unittest


def fixup_paths(path):
    """Adds GAE SDK path to system path and appends it to the google path
    if that already exists."""
    try:
        import google
        google.__path__.append("{0}/google".format(path))
    except ImportError:
        pass

    sys.path.insert(0, path)


def main(sdk_path, test_path, test_pattern):
    # If the SDK path points to a Google Cloud SDK installation
    # then we should alter it to point to the GAE platform location.
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(sdk_path, 'platform/google_appengine')):
        sdk_path = os.path.join(sdk_path, 'platform/google_appengine')

    # Make sure google.appengine.* modules are importable.
    fixup_paths(sdk_path)

    # Make sure all bundled third-party packages are available.
    import dev_appserver
    dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()

    # Fix google shits
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import devappserver2

    # Start the devappserver
    server_instance = devappserver2.DevelopmentServer()
    server_instance.start()

    # Discover and run tests.
    suite = unittest.loader.TestLoader().discover(test_path, test_pattern)
    suite_result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
    server_instance.stop()
    return suite_result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument(
        'sdk_path',
        help='The path to the Google App Engine SDK or the Google Cloud SDK.')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--test-path',
        help='The path to look for tests, defaults to the current directory.',
        default=os.getcwd())
    parser.add_argument(
        '--test-pattern',
        help='The file pattern for test modules, defaults to *_test.py.',
        default='test_*.py')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    result = main(args.sdk_path, args.test_path, args.test_pattern)

    if not result.wasSuccessful():
        sys.exit(1)
```

But i'm struggling with a strange import error.

I've been searching through Github but I was unable to find anything:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runner.py", line 65, in <module>
    result = main(args.sdk_path, args.test_path, args.test_pattern)
  File "runner.py", line 34, in main
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import devappserver2
  File "/Users/toto/Libraries/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import api_server
  File "/Users/toto/Libraries/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 79, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import wsgi_server
  File "/Users/toto/Libraries/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 48, in <module>
    from cherrypy import wsgiserver
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    from ._cptools import default_toolbox as tools, Tool
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cptools.py", line 33, in <module>
    from cherrypy.lib import auth_basic, auth_digest
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/auth_digest.py", line 27, in <module>
    from six.moves.urllib.request import parse_http_list, parse_keqv_list
ImportError: cannot import name parse_http_list
```

I can't figure out how to fix that import thing :(

Comment: Just guessing: maybe some package versions are incompatible - make sure you use the required versions of `six` and possibly other packages. `parse_http_list` is Python 3 and `six` wraps that for Python2.

Comment: One thing that looks odd: your code is finding cherrypy in your system Python's site-packages directory, but I would have expected it to find the version bundled with the App Engine SDK.

Comment: Finally fixed it by explicitely using the packages from the google appengine sdk (that runs the correct version) and not from the default python environment. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the package six you have installed does not include parse_http_list. Try upgrading the six package:

```
pip install six==1.14.0
```

It could be that the parent package then throws an error, then upgrade that package as well.

Comment: Google App Engine's old standard platform is Python2-only, so upgrading is not necessarily a straightforward solution.

Comment: Then try upgrading the six package and see if any errors roll out of this. Curious about the result.

Comment: Finally fixed it by explicitely using the packages from the google appengine sdk (that runs the correct version) and not from the default python environment. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Good luck with further development!